# Fixed footer - How to block page content but display background colour?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This question is difficult to explain. I have a fixed footer with a 10px border at the top. I need the 10px border to block page content like text and images and just show the background colour of the content underneath.

Is there a way to do this? I'm using bootstrap.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1evqnxe/19/)

```
div.customfooter {
  position:fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 500;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

EDIT: The background colour of the content underneath changes throughout the page

Comment: Change `border-top: 10px solid transparent;` to `border-top: 10px solid colorOfYourBackground;`. As I see it.

Comment: @AjAX - Thanks for the reply. Sorry I should have stated that the background colour of the content underneath changes throughout the page

Comment: You can only do that with `Javascript`. And if there are no images.

Comment: :-( There will be images too. Ok thanks for the help, I will work out a different design

Answer (score 0):

You stack div:s with z-index. Normally you would need minimum 2 divs to be able to stack them. You basically need to add another div and set that div to position relative and add z-index. The div that you are planning to have "on-top" should have the highest z-index value.

See below code snippet:

```css
.footer {
position: fixed;
z-index: 2;
background-color: black;
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
}

.content {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
background-color: red;
height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="footer"></div>
<div class="content">
1<br /><br />
2<br /><br />
3<br /><br />
4<br /><br />
5

</div>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Honestly I'm not sure I understand the answer. There is no border (or div acting as a border) on the footer. Could you update the JSFiddle I created to show how it works?

Comment: Your "div.customfooter" is  acting as a footer border covering the front of the other divs.

Comment: Can you please confirm following understanding:
1) The green coloured footer should always be on front.
2) The text should always show below the green footer.
3) the black square should cover complete background.

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstood the question. It is quite difficult to explain (and understand).

Comment: In the JSFiddle there is a transparent border on the footer. I don't want this to allow page content to be visible. Only the background colour

Comment: Ok, I suggest you make a graphical sketch in a graphical program and share so it is clear what you aim the end-result to be.

Comment: I have created a new version of the JSFiddle that probably shows the issue better. When the content underneath has a black background I want the border to be black. When the content underneath has a white background I want the border to be white. In the new JSFiddle the border is always white. I need it to be black ONLY when the background colour of the content underneath is black - https://jsfiddle.net/b1evqnxe/23/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your latest updates I suggest following:

1) Decrease margin:
By doing this you will see the background color during scrolling.
Decrease your margin on "div.customfooter", with value:

```
 margin-left: 10px; 

 margin-right: 10px;
```

2) Body adjustment:
if you need the background to reflect your
black color you would need to set the body to margin:0

Add:

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Toolbox I don't think you understand what I'm looking for